# Netflix, 32 bit Chromium, and Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, chromium, netflix

With the end of 32 bit support for Chrome, has anyone made any progress in getting Netflix to work on an Ubuntu 32 bit version of Chromium? At this time, we must either continue to use Chrome without current security updates just to watch Netflix, or use the WINE/Firefox/Silverlight hack - which slows things down to the point that Netflix becomes effectively unwatchable.

The Arch and Slackware communities have both overcame this limitation. If anyone in Ubuntuland has came up with a similar solution, would they care to share it with the rest of us?

Comment: Hmm, I think your information may be a bit dated. Firefox added drm content reproduction some time ago, netflix works out of box now (after enabling drm content of course) so there's no "hack" at all involved.

Answer (score -1):

Google Chrome will drop 32-bit machines but Chromium is still going. ([Source](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/01/google-chrome-linux-32-bit-discontinued))

Just install Chromium instead of Google Chrome. You'll find it in the software centre.

I think that one difference between Google Chrome and Chromium is that there's a plugin called `Widevine Content Decryption Module` installed in Google Chrome by default but not in Chromium.

Try ([this](https://sites.google.com/site/installationubuntu/home/ubuntu-14-04-lts/browser-tweaks-firefox-chromium)):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pipelight-multi
```

then

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable widevine
```

This should install `pipelight` and install the plugin in Chromium.

There's another source that say that you might require to install flash. If so just install it from [Adobe's website](https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/).

Comment: But the problem was watching Netflix's DRM content, which Chrome can do but chromium cannot, without some modification, which is....

Comment: @ubfan1 edited the answer. Try and tell me if things worked